# Which is a standard way to inject a class to another existing one

Tags: c#, class, unit-testing, constructor

I have a class like this:

```
public class myoldClass:ImyoldClass
{
  private string _a; 
  private string _b; 

  public myoldClass (string a, string b)
  {  
      _a = a; 
      _b = b;
   }

}
```

now this class is used in 20 different classes. I want to use the class Memcache (inherited from IMemcache) inside one of the method of myoldClass but if i instantiated that class in the method it is not good at all because that class depends on network connection and cache server availability. Therefore I cannot keep the standard TDD for the solution. The standard way is that i have to instantiate a new class of Memcache and then pass it as a parameter to the constructor. but I have to change the other 20 classed which are using myoldClass. But the other way can be like this:

```
public class myoldClass:ImyoldClass
{
  private string _a; 
  private string _b; 
  private IMemcache _memcache; 

public myoldClass(string a, string b, IMemcache memcache)                  
{
    _a = a; 
    _b = b; 
    _memcache = memcache; 
}
  public myoldClass (string a, string b)
  {  
      _a = a; 
      _b = b;
      _mencache = new Memcache(); 
   }

}
```

in this way those class that are using this class they continue to use it from the old constructor and I instantiate the Memcache directly for them and in Unit testing I use the other constructor which is new and accept IMemcache as one of its parameter.

My question: is it a standard way to solve the problem by adding this second constructor? IS it not better to change all the places that is required than adding this constructor ?

Comment: The standard way of solving the problem is using a Dependency Injection framework to get the insteance of `myoldClass` instead of doing `new myoldClass`.

Comment: Do you mean to get the instance of Memcache() fron Dependency Injection ?  Because the problem here is with Memcache not myoldClass.

Comment: Like @ScottChamberlain said, the standard way is to use a dependency injection framework to construct objects of `myoldClass`.  Once you set up your DI framework, it'll be what's creating all of your instances of `myoldClass`, and that'll stop you from having to go through your code and change dozens of lines of code every time you make a change to the constructor.  A sign of a problematic design is when you have a dependency (`Memcache` in your case) that you're `new`-ing inside of your other classes.  It's best practice to have all of your constructors take an `IMemcache` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If `myoldClass` is an existing class and you want to inject the `IMemcache` argument while keeping backwards compatibility with classes that aren't DI-constructed, you can do this:

```
public myoldClass(string a, string b, IMemcache memcache = null)                  
{
    _a = a; 
    _b = b; 
    _memcache = memCache ?? new Memcache(); 
}
```

A DI container will supply the parameter, but your existing constructor calls will still work.